# Quadratic residue modulo odd power of $2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

If $x$ and $n$ both are odd positive integers, such that, $$x^2 \equiv -1\mod2^n$$  what can we say about $x$ and $n$ ?

Comment: An immediate observation: $n$ cannot be even because that would make $2^n$ a perfect square (and no consecutive numbers except for $0$ and $1$ are perfect squares). In addition, $x$ cannot be even as well.

Comment: Second thought, doesn't Catalan's conjecture (which was proved some time ago) imply that no such values of $x$ and $n$ exist?

Comment: @barakmanos It is amusing that you state the already given info. in the question as your first claim.

Comment: @Broly: It is now that you've mentioned it (didn't notice that).

Comment: Does the first comment mean to say that $x^2\cong -1$ $(mod y)$ has no solution if $y$ is a perfect square? This is false, take $x=7$ and $y=25$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since odd square  $ \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ we infer that if $n \geq 3$, $x^2+1 \equiv 2 \neq -1 \pmod 8$. Thus $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that if $x$ is odd, then $x^2+1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.